# The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
alter FUNCTION [Kuri].[fnGetAge](@kuri_cust_Id int,@amt decimal)
RETURNS SMALLINT
AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @isVallid  bit = 0
    declare @payed decimal(14,2)
    declare @totaltillnow decimal(14,2)
    select @payed = isnull(SUM(Payment.amt),0)  from Kuri.Payment where Payment.Kuri_Cust_ID = @kuri_Cust_id
    select @totaltillnow = isnull(SUM(NextLotAmount),0) from Kuri.Kuri_GivenDetails
    inner join Kuri.kuri_Customer  
    on Kuri_GivenDetails.kuri_Id  = kuri_Customer.kuri_ID 
     where kuri_Customer.kuri_Cust_id =  @kuri_Cust_id
     if((@payed + @amt) < @totaltillnow)
        set @isVallid = 1
        RETURN @isVallid
    END;
GO

ALTER TABLE [Kuri].[Payment]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT PaymentCheck CHECK (kuri.fnGetAge(kuri_Cust_ID,amt) >= 1 )
GO
```

error :

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint
>   "PaymentCheck". The conflict occurred in database "MERP", table
>   "Kuri.Payment".

Table structure is like this

```
CREATE TABLE [Kuri].[Payment](
    [payment_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [payment_Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [bill_No] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [Kuri_Cust_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [vr_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [amt] [decimal](14, 2) NULL,
    [created_ID] [int] NULL,
    [created_Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [modified_ID] [int] NULL,
    [modified_Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [authorized_ID] [int] NULL,
    [authorized_Date] [datetime] NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Payment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  ([payment_ID] ASC)

 ALTER TABLE [Kuri].[Payment]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Payment_kuri_Customer] FOREIGN KEY([Kuri_Cust_ID])
 REFERENCES [Kuri].[kuri_Customer] ([Kuri_Cust_ID])

 ALTER TABLE [Kuri].[Payment] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Payment_kuri_Customer]
```

Comment: I think either `kuri_Cust_ID` isn't an INT in the table, or `amt` isn't a decimal (or both).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As the error clearly states: there are rows in your table that **violate** your check constraint.

Since your check constraint tests for `kuri.fnGetAge(kuri_Cust_ID,amt) >= 1`, 
you can find those rows in violation of this check constraint using

```
  SELECT * FROM Kuri.Payment
  WHERE kuri.fnGetAge(kuri_Cust_ID, amt) < 1
```

Fix or delete those rows, and then you should be fine and your `ALTER TABLE` command should work

Comment: I would say the way marc_s describes it is clear. The error message provided by the app is not clear. It doesn't state that data in the existing table violates the attempted constraint addition. If it had I doubt I or the original poster would have needed to search for an answer. But thanks Marc_s for the clarification, none the less.