# the alter command conflicted with the check constraint (but no rows violate constraint)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, check-constraints

I am trying to add a check constraint on sql server 2008. I am getting the following error when i run this code:

```
alter table db.dbo.myTable add constraint
noWWWifProgramIsKnown check
(dbo.checkcountuniversalservice(A, B,
C)=0 and  program='WWW' )
```

raises error:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint
>   "noWWWifProgramIsKnown". The conflict occurred in database
>   "db", table "dbo.tableuniversalservice".

Marc_s' answer on SO says that this is likely b/c some row violates the constraint:
[The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192857/the-alter-table-statement-conflicted)

However, no rows violate the constraint because this returns 0:

```
select COUNT(*) from db.dbo.tableuniversalservice 
where
(dbo.checkcountuniversalservice(A, B, C)=0
and 
program='WWW'
)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: As well as the table name, your `SELECT` statement appears to be doing the opposite of what you want: you're querying the number of rows that match the `CHECK` criteria and the result is zero. So either there are no rows in the table, or all of them conflict with the `CHECK` constraint. You may have meant to type `SELECT ... WHERE NOT (...)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your check is backwards... in order for the constraint to pass, it should evaluate to `TRUE` or to `UNKNOWN`.  Your `SELECT` statement is telling you that *no rows meet* the constraint instead of telling you that *no rows violate* the constraint.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> CHECK constraints reject values that evaluate to FALSE.

Comment: +1. Please correct though: "in order for the constraint to pass, it should evaluate to `TRUE` or to `UNKNOWN`"