# Issue with check constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to create a check constraint that allow only session of date end session greater than 
 date begin session
like this :

```
alter table Sessionn add constraint checkdate_CK
check ( Sessionn.datebeginsessionstage <Sessionn.dateendsessionstage)
```

but I have a probleme message :

Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "checkdate_CK". The conflict occurred in database "V12013", table "dbo.Sessionn".

Comment: do you get any results when doing `select * from Sessionn where Sessionn.datebeginsessionstage  >=Sessionn.dateendsessionstage` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192857/the-alter-table-statement-conflicted)

Comment: ow thank you so mush  @Raphaël Althaus i have understood my probleme i was enter data that have the same date