# How to restrict the DIV tags while saving in to the table through Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, constraints

I would like to prevent the `<div>` tag from appearing in a certain column when inserting/updating data in a table.

Suppose the text inserted is: `this is the test text <div> Hai</div>`. Now I don't want to save text like that.

Do I need to go for the Check constraint for this?

Comment: Could you clarify: do you want INSERT/UPDATE statements to fail if they have the `<div>` tag in it? Or do you want to make it so that when text with a `<div>` tag in it is saved/changed, that the text is processed to remove the whole `<div>` element?

Comment: I want to do it when Inserting/updating as well, whenever the text contains <div> in it.

Comment: But **what** exactly do you want to do: 1/ should an INSERT/UPDATE statements fail when the text has a <div> tag in it, or 2/ do you want to make it so that when text with a <div> tag in it is saved/changed, that the text is processed to remove the whole <div> element? Pick 1 or 2.

Comment: When I execute the query `alter table Mytable
Add constraint chk_no_div_tag check(charindex('<div',Mycolumn)=0)` It is giving the following error **The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "chk_no_div_tag". The conflict occurred in database "mydatabase", table "dbo.Mytable", column 'Mycolumn'.**

Comment: 1st one please. The statement will have to fail.

Comment: Ok, then the constraint I posted as an answer should solve your problem.

Comment: did you see my comment above

Comment: Regarding the error you get, read about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192857/the-alter-table-statement-conflicted). In short, you already have data in your table that contains `<div>` tags. First you need to clean up the data to no longer contain the <div> tags before you can add the constraint.

Comment: Updated my answer with what you need to do if the table already contains invalid text.

Comment: Done and accepted answe as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` to do this. Your constraint would look like the following:

```
ALTER TABLE
  your_table
ADD CONSTRAINT 
  chk_no_div_tag CHECK (CHARINDEX('<div',your_column)=0);
```

But first you will have to be sure that no invalid text is in the column before you can apply this constraint. You can delete this invalid data first before adding the constraint:

```
DELETE FROM your_table WHERE CHARINDEX('<div',your_column)<>0;
```